# How to pass a method's nested procedure as a parameter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, freepascal

Given a `TForm` with a `TListBox` on it, the following works:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure _WorkOnListBox;
  begin
    ListBox.Items.Append('Test');
  end;
begin  
  _WorkOnListBox;
end;
```

As does the following:

```
procedure TForm1.DoWithoutListBoxEvents(AProc: TProc);
begin
  ListBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    AProc;  
  finally
    ListBox.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoWithoutListBoxEvents(procedure
  begin
    LayersListBox.Items.Append('Test'); 
  end);
end;
```

But the following does not:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure _WorkOnListBox;
  begin
    ListBox.Items.Append('Test');
  end;
begin  
  DoWithoutListBoxEvents(_WorkOnListBox);
end;
```

I get an `E2555 Cannot capture symbol '_WorkOnListBox'`. Why? Is there any way to get the `DoWithoutListBoxEvents` to work without using an anonymous procedure? Although I think it looks elegant with it, I'm trying to stay FPC compatible.

Comment: @KromStern FreePascal compatibility

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Added the tag for you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DoWithoutEvents()` takes a `TProc` as input:

```
type
  TProc = procedure;
```

Only a **standalone non-class procedure** and an **anonymous procedure** can be assigned to a `TProc`.  `_WorkOnForm` is neither of those, it is a **local procedure** instead.  A local procedure has special compiler handling that ties it to its parent's stack frame.  Thus, `_WorkOnForm` is not compatible with `TProc`.

Comment: Is there any type I can use?

Comment: Not for a local procedure, no.  It is not safe to call a local procedure indirectly (the call will not be set up correctly at the call site), so don't even try to do it.  Local procedures are meant to be called directly, in a way the compiler sees it so it sets up the call correctly.  It is the same reason that makes it dangerous to use a local procedure as an API callback (bad call setup). Just don't do it.